# What does the term "Serializable" mean?

Tags: java, serializable

Not quite sure by the definitions I have read what serializable actually does...

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.StringCharacterIterator;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public final class SavingsAccount implements Serializable {
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean

Comment: ah that's exactly what i'm looking for. So basically using Serializable, it will allow me to save?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `implements Serializable` you can convert an object in bytes, so the object can be send across the network, can be saved in a directory, and rebuild in the other side of the network, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization allows you to turn your class (if it implements `Serializable`) into a data stream and be transfered over a network, or saved onto disk.

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) should give you some good examples and a good description.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization in general means that at the language level there exists a certain level at which entities of the language can be "persisted" in some form, and read back from that persisted form.

That persisted form is more often than not a stream of bytes, which is saved into a file; and you read back from that file in order to recreate the entity at runtime.

In Java, the basic entity which can be persisted/serialized is an `Object`; and in order for it to be a candidate for serialization, it must implement the `Serializable` interface.

Now, this particular interface is a trap; it has many, many conditons to it being implemented correctly. Among others:

- ideally, you want all of your `Serializable` instances to define a `private static final long serialVersionUUID`, and yes, here, the name of the variable matters, it cannot be anything else;
- you may have instance variables in your object which you *do not* want to serialize: those should be marked as `transient`;
- you should ensure that all instance variables, apart from the `transient` ones, are themselves serializable; if not you *must* implement, at the very least, the `{read,write}Object()` methods, or to an even finer grained resolution, `readResolve()` and `writeReplace()`.

In other words: good luck!

Note: maybe you also want to have a look at `Externalizable`.