# Why do we need serialVersionUID when extending RuntimeException?

Tags: java, serialization, runtimeexception, serialversionuid

Why do we need serialVersionUID when extending RuntimeException?  Is RuntimeException a serializable class?

```
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {       
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public DataNotFoundException(String str)
    {
        super(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html)?

Answer (score 6):

`RuntimeException` extends `Exception`. `Exception` extends `Throwable`. `Throwable` implements `Serializable`. So `DataNotFoundException` is `Serializable` too

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Throwables are Serializable. Serializable means that objects of that class can be converted into a sequence of bytes, which can be reassembled by another jvm. Making an exception serializable means it can be transferred across the network between tiers of a distributed application.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions Classes or any classes which implements `Serializable` would need to have `SerialUID`, so that class that has do be serialized at the time of compiling, and `de-serialized` at the time of recompiling, `JVM` will do version matching which version of serialized class is being `de-serialized`.
`Serialisation` is implemented for following reasons.

1. Support bidirectional communication between different versions of a class operating in different virtual machines by:

   - Defining a mechanism that allows `JavaTM` classes to read streams written by older versions of the same class.
   - Defining a mechanism that allows `JavaTM` classes to write streams intended to be read by older versions of the same class.
   - Provide default serialization for persistence and for `RMI`.
   - Perform well and produce compact streams in simple cases, so that `RMI` can use serialization.
   - Be able to identify and load classes that match the exact class used to write the stream.
   - Keep the overhead low for non-versioned classes.
     Use a stream format that allows the traversal of the stream without having to invoke methods specific to the objects saved in the stream.