# How to Convert a user defined object to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, outputstream

I am trying to convert an object called *lineId* that defined by me to byte array in order to feed it back to OutputStream.write

```
static void serialize(IACLineSegment objectToSerialze, OutputStream outputStream) {
    ConductingEquipmentSerializer.serialize(objectToSerialze, outputStream);
    byte[] bytes
    ID lineId = objectToSerialze.getLine().getId();
    if (lineId != null){
      outputStream.write(//lineId byte array);
      }
```

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean for some pointers about serialization.