# Is it possible to convert a custom ArrayList to an to byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Is it possible to convert a custom ArrayList to an to byte array? And if so how would I do that.

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(clientQuery);
            MovieTableBean mTB;

            ArrayList<MovieTableBean> moviesList = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                mTB = new  MovieTableBean(rs.getInt("movieId"),
                        rs.getString("movieName"),
                        rs.getString("description"),
                        rs.getInt("genreId"));
                moviesList.add(mTB);
            }
```

How can I convert

```
ArrayList<MovieTableBean>
```

to an array of bytes?

I could not find any other questions that answered this, if you know of one please comment the link. Thanks.

Comment: Mind to explain why do you need that?

Comment: I want to sent the ArrayList through a OutputStream, but cannot do that in its current state

Comment: Just make sure your MovieTableBean is serializable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836646/java-serializable-object-to-byte-array

Comment: sorry if this sounds stupid, but I am a noob in java, but why make it serializable. What will that help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean