# Why Apache Commons library validator are Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-commons

I was gooing through the source code Apache commons library. My question is why they are using `Serializable` for every validator class e.g. [EmailValidatore](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.java), [ISBNValidator](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/ISBNValidator.java) class ?

It has confused me with use case of `Serializable`. Can anyone justify the use case of `Serializable` here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429921/what-does-serializable-mean

Comment: I see those objects hold configuration in their state. It's typical for such objects to be used in application/session scopes, where it happens that objects get serialized/deserialized following user interaction patterns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more. What i see that their all variables for used by them self and not from outside so the state is very much private